# Definition of Avodah Zarah

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, avodah-zarah, theology

Looking at different explanations regards Avodah Zarah, different/various forms of idolatry, I tried to sum things up, I tried to get to get a definition out of it based on their common denominator.

Avodah Zarah (strange service/worship);

*The adjective in ‘strange service’ has two senses. One is the strangeness of the object toward which the service/worship is directed, not the ‘proper G-d’ but other ‘gods’. The other refers to the method of service/worship, strange in the sense one serves in a matter that is strange to the Torah, strange to the ‘proper’ way of service.*

[which in essence could imply the belief in a certain idea, image or object].

So we got a strange method of worship one the one hand and strange object of worship on the other. Is this what Avodah Zarah is? Or is there more to it?

Comment: "Avodah Zarah (strange service/worship); The adjective in ‘strange service’ has two senses. One is the strangeness of the object toward which the service/worship is directed": wouldn't that one be _avodas zara_ in the construct?

Comment: @msh210 that’s my question, but thanks for affirming

Comment: If that's your question, you should really put it in the question post. It's not there, as far as I can see.

Comment: Why are you stuck with "strange"? You probably mistake it with contemporary "מוזר" which is "strange". זר is translated as "foreign", "alien", "unsuitable" etc. AZ is foreign to the Jews. There's nothing strange/weird about it.

Comment: I -1ed the question, because it is unclear whether you ask for a definition or try to fit your definition in. Please clarify, b/c I think Rambam is very clear and your "strange" comparison is not.

Comment: @AlBerko Most dictionaries define idolatry as the worship fysical objects as god, but avodah zarah seems to apply also to 'strange service', an example of this is the strange fire which the sons of Aharon brought before G-d, their object towards which their service was directed wasn't an idol, but the method of their service is considered avodah zarah. Your answer (below) seems to focus on deities, bodies or objects.. while actions that do not involve any idol are not taken into account. But maybe I misunderstood your recap on the Rambam.

Comment: You're seemingly wrong, and stop using "strange". Nadav and Avihu lighted "improper" or "unsuitable" fire. There was no trace of idolatry. If you claim it was please bring sources.

Comment: @AlBerko I don't like the tone in your writing. Mechon mamre translates vayikra 10:2 as strange fire, sefaria as alien fire; I agree it means improper or unseuitable. The point is that some rabbi's suggest that the esh zarah was linked to avodah zarah, foreign or prohibited worship, a type of idolatry.

Comment: "The Mefarshim explain that Uza replicated the sin of Nadav and Avihu, as he crossed the same forbidden threshold Nadav and Avihu had crossed. The common denominator of the Shitos in what Aveira Nadav and Avihu committed all explain their being makriv an Aish Zara similar to avoda zara- a foreign servitude, saying- I decide on how I want to serve Hashem. This was Uzas sin in his attempt to come close to the Aron Hashem in a way he saw fit, an obvious correlation between the Parsha and Haftara." - https://www.passaiccliftonkollel.org/parshas-shemini-2/

Comment: if you say "*some rabbis suggest *" please quote those Rabbis exactly. I'm not aware of anybody mentioning AZ with Nadav and Avihu.

Comment: Oh! Do you mean to point to a contradiction between the body of worship and the method of worship? Like if one is worshipping Hashem with a way not mentioned in the Torah it would be considered AZ?

Comment: @AlBerko yes, you seem to understand what I'm trying to say. P.s. it was Rabbi Baruch Frydman-Kohl who wrote 'that some rabbis suggest... etc.' so I took his word to be true.

Comment: P.s. (Shabat 105b, Sotah 4b, 5a) The Talmud even seems to define certain actions based on negative emotions as Avodah Zarah (for example out of control anger) even though there are no obviously ‘religious’ actions involved, nor does the classic worship something else as G-d applies.

Answer (score 2):

[Rambam, Hilchos Avodah Zarah 2:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912360/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Two.htm):

> עיקר הצווי בעבודת כוכבים שלא לעבוד אחד מכל הברואים לא מלאך ולא גלגל ולא כוכב ולא אחד מארבעה היסודות ולא אחד מכל הנבראים מהן
>
> The essence of the commandment [forbidding] the worship of false gods is not to serve any of the creations, not an angel, a sphere, or a star, none of the four fundamental elements, nor any entity created from them.

Also, ibid. 2:6:

> כל המודה בעבודת כוכבים שהיא אמת אף על פי שלא עבדה הרי זה מחרף ומגדף את השם הנכבד והנורא
>
> Whoever accepts a false god as true, even when he does not actually worship it, disgraces and blasphemes [God's] glorious and awesome name.

Indeed, accepting such a god verbally as one's deity is also counted as avodah zarah, and is punishable by execution (ibid. 3:4).

Answer (score 0):

Let me just recap on [Rambam's Yesodey Hatorah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.1?lang=bi):

1. G-d is one and only and omnipresent and omni-everything. But wait, what are we, then? What about the rest of the creation - Sun, Moon, Earth, mountains, trees et all - does it all exist or not?
2. As you see the idea of one G-d is impractical, for we have to admit the existence of other bodies and powers *within* the Creation, for example, Sun is a physical body, Sun exerts [gravitational, thermal] powers onto Earth and us, or angels are spiritual bodies that can exert powers on humans and the rest of the creation. This idea aligns perfectly with the Torah.
3. **Idolatry is about two things**:

   - **Acknowledging that those bodies have independence from the Creator**. That they act on their own, according to their own will.
   - **Worshiping those bodies in actions, esteeming and admiring them in thoughts**.
4. As Rambam starts [Hilchot Avoda Zara](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.1?lang=bi), mere acknowledging #2 (the existence of other bodies and powers) is not AZ per se. But forgetting whence their powers come from (aka G-d) and worshipping them is what's forbidden.